# How to use field_groups in admin only?

Tags: 7, entities

I want to use field_groups in my content type to make it easier to deal with a long content type, but I don't want that group (probably a fieldset) to be rendered at all on the client-facing side.

How do I control that?

Comment: by admin only, do you mean user 1 or when any user is editting the node ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS to change the div created by the field group.  Set margin, padding, border and font-size to 0.

Don't hide the div because that will hide the contents of the div.

Comment: It looks like the name of the field_group is also output with the div.  Is there a more elegant way to suppress that than hiding with css?

Comment: Sweet.  I see that the group name can be hidden via `content type` > `manage display` > [settings button for field group].